# Is there a way to convert 24hour time format into four categories or four quadrants of the day?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I am trying to pre-process timestamp in my data into four categories of the day.

This means i need to convert object data type to categories namely

Morning for 00:00:00 to 11:59:59

Afternoon for 12:00:00 to 15:59:59

Evening for 16:00:00 to 19:59:59

Night for 20:00:00 to 23:59:59

my timestamp data looks like

```
transaction timestamp
08:26:00
08:26:00
08:26:00
08:26:00
12:26:00
12:45:00
16:26:00
16:28:00
20:28:00
20:34:00
```

I expect the output to of the above mentioned column to be

```
time of day
Morning
Morning
Morning
Morning
Afternoon
Afternoon
Evening
Evening
Night
Night
```

How shall i clean this type of data and convert it to just 4 categories?

Comment: If still problem with solution, let me know.

Comment: yes, i am not able to implement that for my data, its confusing. That solution you mentioned can be binned separately by defining each bin size. Here its difficult because its time. How to proceed with object data which describes time?

Comment: Try convert them to timedeltas.

Comment: i tried ```data_clean['time_of_day(hh:mm:ss)'].map(lambda x: pd.to_timedelta(x))```.......okay now it worked..after this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert values to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and then use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
df['transaction timestamp'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['transaction timestamp'])
#if values are python object times convert to strings
#df['transaction timestamp'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['transaction timestamp'].astype(str))

b = pd.to_timedelta(['00:00:00','12:00:00','16:00:00','20:00:00', '24:00:00'])
l = ['Morning','Afternoon','Evening','Night']
df['time of day'] = pd.cut(df['transaction timestamp'], bins=b, labels=l)

print (df)
  transaction timestamp time of day
0              08:26:00     Morning
1              08:26:00     Morning
2              08:26:00     Morning
3              08:26:00     Morning
4              12:26:00   Afternoon
5              12:45:00   Afternoon
6              16:26:00     Evening
7              16:28:00     Evening
8              20:28:00       Night
9              20:34:00       Night
```